# Removing fuel pump fuse on diesel engine

Tags: fuel-system, diesel, fuse, pump

If I were to remove the fuel pump fuse on a Hyundai i30 CRDi diesel and then try to start the engine, would I need to bleed the fuel line or would it be okay?

Comment: What's make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

Comment: 2013 Hyundai i30 ctdi. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I don't have any experience with the Hyundai ctdi engines, but would assume since you are not breaking open any lines, you'll not have an issue with needing to bleed them after pulling the fuel pump fuse. I believe most newer diesel cars have a return style diesel system which doesn't need bleeding even if you break open a line. I don't think you'll have issues, but would suggest you wait for a more authoritative answer than my comment.

Comment: Crank with fuse removed?